# Minimum OS Version Mismatch

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, app-store-connect, ios8.1

I am trying to set iOS 8.1 as minimum deployment target in XCode 6.1 but on submission to itunes connect i get "Invalid Binary" error.

Minimum OS Version Mismatch - The minimum OS version (LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS) in the binary ('8.0') for architecture ('armv7') differs from the MinimumOSVersion ('8.1') in the Info.plist.

Minimum OS Version Mismatch - The minimum OS version (LC_VERSION_MIN_IPHONEOS) in the binary ('8.0') for architecture ('arm64') differs from the MinimumOSVersion ('8.1') in the Info.plist.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the deployment target both in your Info.plist and in your build settings (`IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`, also named iOS Deployment Target) . Look at your build log and check that the `-miphoneos-version-min` flag is set correctly.

Comment: App extension deployment and App deployment target were different in mine.